# How can I make a button look like a link - specifically: text-decoration underline / bottom border

Tags: html, css

How can I make a button look like an anchor tag?

I tried the HTML below, but when I hover over the button, the bottom border doesn't look the same as other anchor tags.  The border bottom looks to be about 3px below the text, while on a anchor tags, there is only 1px between them.

I would just use a link, but I have read that a button would be more semantically correct for my situation.

```
<style>
.epUnsubscribe {
    float: left;
}

    .epUnsubscribe button {
        background: none!important;
        border: none;
        padding: 0!important;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
        color: #5C8C9B;
    }

        .epUnsubscribe button:hover {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #5C8C9B;
        }
</style>

<div style="float: left" class="epUnsubscribe">
        <button id="BtnUnsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Giving the element a `padding-bottom:-2px;` may do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't a border on hyperlinks, it is an underline, try this:

```
.epUnsubscribe button:hover {
  border: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: thanks!  I copy and posted the border from another SO answer, and don't know how I overlooked it.  I guess it's Monday morning!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use an actual link and give it some button functionality using `onclick="..."` callback.

Answer (score -1):

Links don't have bottom borders, they have underlines

```
text-decoration:underline
```